# Sequelize: don't return password

Tags: sequelize.js, password-storage

I'm using Sequelize to do a DB find for a user record, and I want the default behavior of the model to **not** return the `password` field for that record.  The `password` field is a hash but I still don't want to return it.

I have several options that will work, but none seems particularly good:

1. Create a custom class method `findWithoutPassword` for the `User` model and within that method do a `User.find` with the `attributes` set as shown in the [Sequelize docs](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models/#find-search-for-one-specific-element-in-the-database)
2. Do a normal `User.find` and filter the results in the controller (not preferred)
3. Use some other library to strip off unwanted attributes

Is there a better way?  Best of all would be if there is a way to specify in the Sequelize model definition to never return the `password` field, but I haven't found a way to do that.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I would suggest overriding the `toJSON` function:

```
sequelize.define('user', attributes, {
  instanceMethods: {
    toJSON: function () {
      var values = Object.assign({}, this.get());

      delete values.password;
      return values;
    }
  }
});
```

Or in sequelize v4

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', attributes, {});

User.prototype.toJSON =  function () {
  var values = Object.assign({}, this.get());

  delete values.password;
  return values;
}
```

`toJSON` is called when the data is returned to the user, so end users won't see the password field, but it will still be available in your code.

`Object.assign` clones the returned object - Otherwise you will completely delete the property from the instance.

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  Would this preclude ever getting the password (or other blacklisted attributes) out of the model?

Comment: EDIT: this is not filtering out the password for me.  Looks like the instanceMethod `toJSON` isn't getting called for the return of either `user.get()` or `user.dataValues`.  Should I be using another method to return attributes?

Comment: You should either call `toJSON`, or just return the user object. For example `res.send(200, user)` will internally call `JSON.stringify` on the user object, which in turn calls `toJSON`

Comment: IMPORTANT!  If you follow the above to the letter, `delete values.password` will actually remove the password attribute *from the user instance* - not just JSON output.  Use `var values = Object.assign({}, this.get())` or appropriate polyfill to avoid mutating the actual user's properties.

Comment: got error while using above code `Unhandled rejection Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: @AkshayPratapSingh Are you using an arrow function?

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier yeah

Comment: You can't do that in this case - we use `.bind` to set the context to the instance - But you can't do that with arrow functions

Comment: This will work if you're just creating a JSON representation of a user. BUT! If you include a user from another model, the `toJSON` that gets called is the other models! This will cause you to leak your hashed password out when user's are eagerly loaded. See this: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3891

Comment: this does not work anymore with sequelize 4, instanceMethods are deprecated, replace with this Model.prototype.someMethod = function () {..}, according  to this http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html#breaking-changes

Comment: I want to exclude certain attributes after a `create` - is that possible? The `toJSON` approach is doing it all the time, that is not working for me.

Comment: Instead of `Object.assign({}, this.get())` you can use `this.get({ clone: true })`

Comment: ES syntax makes this nice and tidy: `{ ...this.get(), password: undefined }`

Comment: This method will only work when directly fetching this model. It will not exclude the attribute through associations. So, if you fetch `UserTransactions` and include `Users`, the user password will show up in the response. The `defaultScope` answer below solves this problem.

Comment: Is there any why to override the `toJSON` function for all Models at once and not per each Model?

Answer (score 124):

Another way is to add a default scope to the User model.

Add this in the model's options object

```
defaultScope: {
  attributes: { exclude: ['password'] },
}
```

Or you can create a separate scope to use it only in certain queries.

Add this in the model's options object

```
scopes: {
  withoutPassword: {
    attributes: { exclude: ['password'] },
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in queries

```
User.scope('withoutPassword').findAll();
```

Comment: IMPORTANT! This is the only answer that worked for me. It is important to know that accepted anwser will work ONLY if you directly fetch user model. If you include user model throug another model toJSON functio in user model will not get called and you will leak your passwords to the client!!

Comment: that's the best answer. I don't know why that is not on the top.

Comment: NOTE: This answer works fine but the excluded field will still be exposed for `create`. Overriding `toJSON` protects the field from being exposed during create.

Comment: @DeanKoštomaj .Using toJSON worked fine for me when using include in findAll. The deleted field wasn't included.

Comment: @DeanKoštomaj. Noticed the problem when I tried including Parent in the child.

Comment: This still works in Sequelize 5. Also, it's a great solution!

Comment: @nonybrighto Wouldn't you want to expose the password field for `create`? Its needed to set the user's password when their account gets created.

Comment: @pawan samdani   Yes, It is needed, but if you will send the created user as JSON after creation, you will also be sending the password too.

Comment: This comment brought exactly what I needed but I still didn't know. Very good thank you!!

Below is a link to the scope definitions

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html

Comment: @nonybrighto Thanks for highlighting that security flaw with this solution! The best fix I found is to add `await user.reload();` in an `afterCreate` [hook](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/hooks.html) for the model.

Comment: For people who want to use the scope way inside an include for relational tables:
include: {
     model: models.users.scope('withoutPassword'),
     as: "developer"
},

Answer (score 39):

I like to use a combination of both of Pawan's answers and declare the following:

```
defaultScope: {
    attributes: { exclude: ['password'] },
},
scopes: {
    withPassword: {
        attributes: { },
    }
}
```

This allows me to exclude the password by default and use the `withPassword` scope to explicitly return the password when needed, such as when running a login method.

```
userModel.scope('withPassword').findAll()
```

This ensure that the password is not returned when including the user via a referenced field, e.g.

```
accountModel.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: userModel,
        as: 'user'
    }]
})
```

Comment: This should be the best practice!

Answer (score 32):

Maybe you can just add `exclude` at your attribute when you `find`, look like this:

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', attributes);

User.findAll({
    attributes: {
        exclude: ['password']
    }
});
```

Read the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/querying/#attributes) for more details

Comment: adding the block of `attributes` to each query is not so good. a way to define exclude attributes on the model level to apply all queries is needed!

Answer (score 5):

The code below worked for me. We wanted access to the instance attributes at runtime but remove them before sending the data to the client.

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/dbname')

const PROTECTED_ATTRIBUTES = ['password', 'token']

const Model = Sequelize.Model

class User extends Model {
  toJSON () {
    // hide protected fields
    let attributes = Object.assign({}, this.get())
    for (let a of PROTECTED_ATTRIBUTES) {
      delete attributes[a]
    }
    return attributes
  }
}

User.init({
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true
    }
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  token: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(16),
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
},
{
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'user'
})

module.exports = User
```

[Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/arivia/2afbf227595fb5db24149e69fa8736e7)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this working by adding a getter to the field which returns `undefined`

```
firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      get() {
        return undefined;
      }
    }
```

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979695/1346528) does not work when the model is included from another model.

I had a virtual field, say `fullName` that depends on the fields that I wanted to hide, say `firstName` and `lastName`. And the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48357983/1346528) based on `defaultScope` does not work in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I struggled for an hour to find the solution where I needed to hide the column but show in some virtual field.

Answer (score 0):

there's a plugin for [scoping attributes](https://github.com/mickhansen/ssacl-attribute-roles) as discussed [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1462).

i went with the override as mentioned in the accepted answer, except i called the original `toJSON` rather than `get` with `this.constructor.super_.prototype.toJSON.apply(this, arguments)` as described in the [api docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#definemodelname-attributes-options-model)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simple way by excluding attributes. See the below code (comment line)

```
    Patient.findByPk(id, {
            attributes: {
              exclude: ['UserId', 'DiseaseId'] // Removing UserId and DiseaseId from Patient response data
            },
            include: [
              { 
                model: models.Disease
              },
              {
                model: models.User,
                attributes: {
                  exclude: ['password'] // Removing password from User response data
                }
              }
           ]
    })
    .then(data => {
        res.status(200).send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: `Error retrieving Patient with id ${id} : ${err}`
        });
    });
```