# Sequelize: Don't return password on Create

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When I create a new instance of my User with Sequelize, I get the full object returned from the database as a response to the Create. I'm trying to prevent Sequelize from returning the hashed password stored in my User table on create.

```
exports.create = (payload, err, success) => {
  db.user.create(payload).then(success).catch(err);
  console.log('Created new user record.');
};
```

I tried using the exclude property, but the full object returns.

```
exports.create = (payload, err, success) => {
  db.user.create(payload, {
    attributes: {
      exclude: ['password']
    }
  }).then(success).catch(err);
  console.log('Created new user record.');
};
```

I am able to use the exclude property in attributes on my find and findAll routes like the example below, but I haven't been able to get it to work with my create.

```
exports.find = (payload, err, success) => {
  db.user.find({
    where: {
     id: payload.id,
    },
    attributes: {
      exclude: ['password']
    }
  }).then(success).catch(err);
  console.log('Retrieved user record with id: ' + payload.id);
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequelize: don't return password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972271/sequelize-dont-return-password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [toJSON](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-toJSON) instance method to exclude attributes:

Model:

```
instanceMethods: {
      toJSON: function () {
          const userObj = Object.assign({}, this.dataValues);

          delete userObj.password;

          return userObj
      }
}
```

Route file:

```
user.create(request.body, (err) => {
  res.status(500).json(err);
  console.log('Error creating new user.');
}, (data) => {
  res.status(200).json(data.toJSON());
  console.log('User created.'); 
});
```

Comment: The returned object is the same with the password when adding this to my User model create. Or would I add it somewhere else? To the sequelize.define maybe?

Comment: @Wheezykw Are you calling toJSON method from your User instance? `user.toJSON();`

Comment: I added the instanceMethods to the User instance in my model. In my express route, I do the following:

    `user.create(request.body, (err) => {
        res.status(500).json(err);
        console.log('Error creating new user.')
     }, (data) => {
        res.status(200).json(data);
        console.log('User created.')
     });`

Comment: `user.create(request.body, (err) => { res.status(500).json(err); console.log('Error creating new user.') }, (data) => { res.status(200).json(data.toJSON()); console.log('User created.') });` should works.

Comment: Thank you @Andrés Andrade this works very well. I was focusing on the model and not on the response.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Getter on your model and return undefined

```
password: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  get() {
     return undefined;
    }
}
```