# Sequelize - Don't return password with JSON response

Tags: json, express, sequelize.js

I use **Sequelize 4.22.6** with **ExpressJS**.

I **want hide password** and others fields when I create an user with this:

```
models.User.create({
    firstName: 'Maxence',
    lastName: 'Rose',
    email: 'email@domain.tld',
    password: 'azeaze',
}).then((result) => {
    res.json(result.toJSON()); // I don't want return "password" field
});
```

I tried this: [Sequelize: don't return password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972271/sequelize-dont-return-password) & this [Sequelize: Don't return password on Create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655612/sequelize-dont-return-password-on-create)

```
instanceMethods: {
    toJSON: () => {
        console.log("Console log here...");
    }
}
```

But, I have the impression **instanceMethods()** method isn't called.

I have put a **console.log()** function in this **instanceMethods()** and I can't see this log in console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue before with the sequelize. I worked around with something like:

Your `models/user.js` file:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
 const User = sequelize.define(
 'user',
 {
   // your columns here
 });

 User.prototype.toJSON = function(){
   console.log("Console log here...");
 };    

 return User;
});
```

Then you can call the instance method on a created user object.