# Sequelize. Right way to populate data and remove keys from output?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How to remove some fields of model from `find*` (Like password, token)?
I think overriding `toJSON()` function (Like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979695/6119618) is not a good way, because i sometimes need this field for password validation or token for checking etc..
Is there something like as `.select('+token')` as mongoose has?

And another question i think it's fit this topic.
How to remove generated by `through` fields from `find*` output?
When i call `User.find()` it responds `{ id: 0, name: 'somename', UserProjectsTie: { /* complex object of many-to-many relation table */ } }`

Answer (score 0):

To exclude an attribute from find*:

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: { exclude: ['baz'] }
});
```

To make this the default behavior, use a [scope](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/scopes.html):

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
  // Attributes
}, {
  defaultScope: {
    attributes: { exclude: ['baz'] }
  }
});
```

Unless I'm mistaken the 'through' should only show up when using 'include'.  To get rid of through in that case:

```
Model.findAll({
  include: [{association: 'OtherModels', through: {attributes: []}}]
});
```

Comment: I have to do that in each query. I want to invert this behavoir to include fields only when i need that

Comment: When you define your object, you can use a scope to set the default to not provide a field.  http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/scopes.html  (updated answer to reflect this)