# Password field being returned in SequelizeUniqueConstraintError

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I am creating a RESTful API application and I am running into an issue with the password being returned in an error response. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to exclude the field.

This is the current response:

```
"status": "Unique Constraint Error",
    "message": "Validation error",
    "data": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "username must be unique",
                "type": "unique violation",
                "path": "username",
                "value": "JamesBond4",
                "origin": "DB",
                "instance": {
                    "id": null,
                    "username": "JamesBond4",
                    "password": "$2b$10$ep5TQsgLhgmwJiuRwk3vTex7xq3rQbyobjFiu3Mx7A4J1MqleQnGO",
                    "email": "jb@gmail4.com",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-09-19T15:20:13.129Z",
                    "createdAt": "2023-09-19T15:20:13.129Z"
                },
                "validatorKey": "not_unique",
                "validatorName": null,
                "validatorArgs": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see the response contains the password field. I want the response to remain mostly the same, just sanitize the password from the response.

My model already has the scope altered to not include the password in any queries without special coding to retrieve it.

```
{
    sequelize,
    modelName: "Profile",
    defaultScope: {
        attributes: { exclude: ["password"] },
    },
}
```

Currently this is a findAll API call:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "JamesBond",
        "email": "jb@gmaill.com",
        "createdAt": "2023-09-19T12:57:36.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-09-19T12:57:36.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "JamesBond2",
        "email": "jb@gmail.com",
        "createdAt": "2023-09-19T14:03:10.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-09-19T14:03:10.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "username": "JamesBond3",
        "email": "jb@gmail3.com",
        "createdAt": "2023-09-19T14:28:15.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-09-19T14:28:15.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "username": "JamesBond4",
        "email": "jb@gmail4.com",
        "createdAt": "2023-09-19T14:30:27.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-09-19T14:30:27.000Z"
    }
]
```

The password is not returned in normal usage - just when an error is thrown.

As a workaround I've implement the following, but I feel there has to be a better way to achieve this. If I forget this later in the code...

```
if (error.name === "SequelizeUniqueConstraintError") {
    delete error.errors[0].instance.password;
    error.errors[0].instance.password = undefined;
     throw new SequelizeUniqueConstraintError(error.errors, error.message);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972271/sequelize-dont-return-password

Comment: This is what I am doing currently, but it doesn't seem to affect the SequelizeUniqueConstraintError output. Yes, the response you gave has a different option, but the difference is I could use if for specific queries. The option I use denies the password on any and all queries.

Comment: It may very well be a bug to report to Sequelize.

Comment: That may be the case, but I have a suspicion that this is working as intended. I think that only because the docs refer to scope as altering queries. It does that as the documentation outlines. The problem I am facing is in the error response if a duplicate entry is attempted. I am going to give it a few days and see if I can come up with a solution before reporting it as a bug.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems fairly insecure to me for a password to be leaked in an error message and is certainly not something that should be default behavior.

Comment: I lean toward agreeing with you about the security, especially since I've taken the step to exclude it from queries and all. I also found a work-around for the moment.